# How to remove gaps for GtkSeparator and GtkListBoxRow in GtkPlacesSidebar?

Tags: css, gtk, themes, styling, gtk3

How to remove gaps for GtkSeparator and GtkListBoxRow in GtkPlacesSidebar?

There is 4 and 2 pixel gaps even when paddings and borders disabled.

[image: gtk places sidebar gaps]

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  -GtkWidget-separator-height: 0;
  -GtkSeparator-separator-height: 0;
  -GtkSeparatorMenuItem-horizontal-padding: 0;
  -GtkSeparatorMenuItem-vertical-padding: 0;
}

GtkSeparator {
  color: #f00;
}

GtkListBoxRow {
  background: #f00;
  color: #fff;
}

GtkPlacesSidebar .sidebar {
  background: #00f;
}
```

Here is source code of [gtkplacessidebar](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/master/gtk/gtkplacessidebar.c) and [gtklistbox](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/a28103cf51459559e4c22ae2d2843edaa94e5ba0/gtk/gtklistbox.c). Do you have any ideas to try?

**UPD**

It's margins that can be removed with Gtk Inspector. But not with CSS and program code.

[image: removed margin with Gtk Inspector]

This code finds childrens of GtkPlacesSidebar and sets their margins, but makes no visual changes.

```py
placessidebar = Gtk.PlacesSidebar()

viewport = placessidebar.get_children()[0]
listbox = viewport.get_children()[0]
sidebarrows = listbox.get_children()

for sidebarrow in sidebarrows:
    print(sidebarrow)
    print(sidebarrow.get_margin_top())
    print(sidebarrow.get_margin_bottom())
    sidebarrow.set_margin_top(88)
    sidebarrow.set_margin_bottom(88)
    print(sidebarrow.get_margin_top())
    print(sidebarrow.get_margin_bottom())
```

prints

```
<gtk.SidebarRow object at 0x7f0368b9e900 (GtkSidebarRow at 0x1bc8370)>
4
1
88
88
<gtk.SidebarRow object at 0x7f0368b9e948 (GtkSidebarRow at 0x1bc8550)>
1
1
88
88
```

**UPD2**

Solved with timeout. Widget adds margins dinamically and if you need to remove them, you should wait at least 200ms after widget showed.

```py
GLib.timeout_add(200, removemargin)
```

Garbage.

Comment: I don't know, but you can use the GTK inspector (Ctrl+Shift+D) to look at what is causing those gaps and try out what CSS you need to eliminate the gaps.

Comment: Yay! Thank you, @ptomato, I found that it's margin attached to GtkSidebarRow through GtkWidget and I can change it with Inspector. But I can't change it with CSS because it's not implemented yet. And I can't change it with code because `set_margin` does nothing for visual effect.

Comment: @ptomato, i found solution, but it's unacceptable...